Unity ADMob ads doesn't show up on the device
This is my android manifest,
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
    <application>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>



I replaced test identities from admob.
My game approved on google admob.
Google admob dependencies.

Used package version.

So summary is ,
unity google admobs,
1 - my game is approved on google admobs,
2 - game already on playstore,
3 -  using unity 9.2.0 admob package and required other things versions etc are correct,
4 - google admobs ids and banner , intersitilal ads ids are set,
5 - build and other things doesnt cause errors,
6 - on unity test ad is shows up correctly,
But the real or test ads are not shows up on the game in the playstore, what is the problem i checked almost everything please help.
